# No se muestran datos de Vue3 en hostinger

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js

Hice una pagina que trae archivos desde una api de laravel

En localhost lo veo bien, inclusive en la pagina de netlify se ve bien, pero en la de hostinger que tengo, sube y la pagina esta en blanco y en consola me tira el error

Uncaught TypeError: El especificador “vue” era un especificador básico, pero no se reasignó a nada. Los especificadores de módulos relativos deben comenzar con “./”, “../” o “/”.

Entiendo que hay algo que no soporta hostinger pero no se que es, cambie los @ en los import de vue pero tampoco, que puede ser??

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y subiste todo lo necesario??? porque ahi parece que falta algo...

Comment: ejecutaste el comando `npm run build`?

Comment: sisi, es mas, hice un proyecto desde cero, sin editar nada, solo instale vue3, la publique en github, y desde netlify se ve bien, pero desde hostinger me tira ese error